# References on Current Algebra

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, quantum-chromodynamics

Although [current algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_algebra) is out of usage from what I hear, I think I see lots of papers (especially dealing with strong interactions) with transition amplitude written with the currents (this is based on current algebra, correct?). I do not understand these very well, so I want to find more references on this. I cannot find any good review papers; do any good review papers come to mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connection with current expectations and current-current correlations is loose only.

There is no comprehensive survey article; key papers are by Goldin and coworkers.

http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/12/3/10.1063/1.1665610

http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/22/8/10.1063/1.525110

You can use scholar.google.com to find many papers citing these.